# is there any method to click a element in Flash player using capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I need to click an element in the webpage. But that element is present in the flash player. I can't took xpath ans CSS also. Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a library that acts like a full-fledged web server, like Poltergeist. Then you can click precise coordinates on the page. That might work. Have a look here: https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#clicking-precise-coordinates

`page.driver.click(x, y)`

where x and y are the screen coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using selenium web-driver 2.25.0. So can you please give me any idea to click an element with selenium web-driver?

Comment: I don't know / think you can even do this with Selenium, but they are both interchangeable with capybara, so you can just use poltergeist as well as capybara